# Change html table row color based on php echo value

Tags: php, html

I have the following in my table

```
<td><?php
 $datetime1 = new DateTime("$rows[activation_time]");
 $datetime2 = new DateTime("$rows[systime]");
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 echo $interval->format(' %H:%i:%s');
 ?></td>
```

I would like to change the row color based on the $interval echo from the calculation.

The following I have tried and it did not work

```
<?php
  $interval = $array_select[array_keys($array_select)[0]];
  if($interval >= '00:05:00'){
  $style = 'style="background-color:#FF0000; text-align: center;border-color: #999999"';
  }elseif($interval <= '00:04:59'){
  $style = 'style="background-color:#009933; text-align: center;border-color: #999999"';
  }
?>
```

I need to change the row color if the time is greater than 5 min or less than 5 min

Comment: $interval >= '00:05:00' is BAD BAD BAD ... string have not comparer to > <. You need make date object

Comment: rather than adding cumbersome inline styles if you were to apply a suitable class to the `table-row` element you could easily style in css using `tr.CLASSNAME > td{}` etc

Comment: First need to convert h:i:s to minutes like $time    = explode(':', $interval);
$minutes = ($time[0] * 60.0 + $time[1] * 1.0);

Comment: After that you can use  $minutes variable for comparison .

Comment: Or another apporch is $minutes = date('i', strtotime($interval));

Comment: I am also getting the following error, Undefined variable '$array_select'

Comment: What you get from $array_select show here